# Webpack 4 production setup with sass and babel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, sass, babeljs

So I want to setup a production build script for my app.

My folder structure is this:

```
public
  - index.html
  - images
      - some_image.png
build
  - bundle.js
  - bundle.map.js
src
  - index.jsx (Entrypoint)
  - js
      - JSX files
  - scss
      - app.scss (imports others)
      - modules, base, ...
```

My current webpack config allows me to launch a dev server with --content-base set to public. This is the config:

```
const path = require("path");

const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: "/",
    },
    devtool: "sourcemap",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader"
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader", options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader", options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    }
};
```

What I would like to achieve is now a webpack build that bundles all my assets in the build folder so I can gzip it and deploy it. Maybe something like this:

```
build
  - index.html
  - bundle.js
  - bundle.css
  - images
```

With this setup I could just deploy this and point nginx to the folder and the app would be ready to go. 
I can't figure out how to achieve this though. Currently all webpack -p does it put a bundle.js in my build folder. I've read about "extract-text-webpack-plugin" but it wouldn't work for me throwing errors (maybe because webpack 4 is not supported?)

Currently webpack is really confusing because most tutorials are for webpack 2 or maybe even 1 and I can't find a good guide for a simple clean config. I don't want to install another 10 npm packages for this to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extract-text-webpack-plugin` is indeed what you're looking for, and it is currently unsupported in Webpack 4 as you guessed. Your best bet is to hold off until it's updated, forked or replaced, or fork it yourself and contribute to its development.

**EDIT:** While `extract-text-webpack-plugin` has been updated to work with Webpack 4, it should no longer be used to bundle CSS files. Use [`mini-css-extract-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) instead.

Comment: There's now `mini-css-extract-plugin` that should get you going in webpack 4.